# what is the difference between type "a" and type "t" in Haskell type signature?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

is there any difference between the two types "a" and "t" in Haskell type signature or its only a different designation like type "a" and type "b"?

in https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html type [a] is defined as followed:

> [a] is the family of types consisting of, for every type a, the type
>   of lists of a. Lists of integers (e.g. [1,2,3]), lists of characters
>   (['a','b','c']), even lists of lists of integers, etc., are all
>   members of this family. (Note, however, that [2,'b'] is not a valid
>   example, since there is no single type that contains both 2 and 'b'.)

is this definition also applied for type "t" ?

an example might be :

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
  app :: [t] -> t -> [t]
```

Comment: That depends on if there is a type restriction in the signature matching those symbols. Show the signature in question.

Comment: No, if the type variables do not occur in type constraints, these are just variables. The name of these variables is arbitrary. But sometimes a more semantical name can be useful. Like `n` for number, etc.

Comment: Not a complete answer but maybe it helps to know that `foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` is equivalent to `foldl :: Foldable x => (y -> z -> y) -> y -> x z -> y` and `app :: [t] -> t -> [t]` is equivalent to `app :: [u] -> u -> [u]`

Comment: Strictly speaking, `t` does not refer to a type; it refers to a type-level function that *returns* a type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Haskell type definitions, type names always start with upper-case letters, whereas type variables always start with lower-case letters. These are normally called `a`, `b`, and so on, but can also be called `f`, `m`, `t`, and so on.

Often, the letters in the beginning of the alphabet are used for unbounded type variables, whereas you often see more specific type variables denoted with `f`, `m`, `t`, and so on.

In the particular example

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

`t` is specifically denoted as being an instance of the `Foldable` type class. `t a` means any `Foldable` 'container' that holds values of the type `a`.

When you look your other example

```
app :: [t] -> t -> [t]
```

it might as well have said `[a] -> a -> [a]`, if `app` is a 'free-standing' function. If, on the other hand, `app` belongs to a type class, that type class definition could contain a more specific definition of `t`.